# App document directory data removed when upgrade ios from 7 to ios 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

In my iOS app I am saving data in the documents directory, and it is all being flagged to NOT sync to the cloud as Apple suggests but when i upgrade my app from ios 7 to ios 8 then my app document directory become empty.

Answer (score 2):

That's because iOS 8 uses a different directory structure than iOS 7 and older.
You can see the same with the iOS 8 simulator where now your app is stored like this:

```
/Users/{YOUR NAME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APPLICATION ID}/
```

You can get your device id by going in Xcode > Window > Devices > Select your device > Identifier.

Comment: You can also check 'xcrun simctl list' from the command line.

Comment: Then all app like whats app who stored the images or audio or video in document directory will faces this issue? It would be very irritating to user to again download the data so their is any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I just want to confirm one more thing that is all images of document directory will also be saved after updating the device to iOS 8 ? only path will be changed or image will also be lose ?

Comment: If you acquire your paths dynamically you should not have any issues. Please accept my answer.